# How to use elsevier scopus api to get list of all author affiliations for a given journal?

Tags: python, api, scopus

I'm new to using an API, and I'm currently trying to use Elsevier API. My goal is to extract the author (university) affiliations for each submission in a given journal. I've set up the API Key and looked at the  [exampleProg.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ElsevierDev/elsapy/master/exampleProg.py) found here.

The [How-To](https://dev.elsevier.com/technical_documentation.html) guides also aren't very helpful with my specific task. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've tried, but I don't have access to the resources (no "Institutional Token"). Your task is to get the university name of the author of journals?

Comment: Can you provide example input parameters you would intend to pass to the Elsevier API and your expected outputs? does your task require an "Institutional Token"? https://dev.elsevier.com/tecdoc_developer_faq.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the [pybliometrics package](https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that we design (we're Scopus users w/o Elsevier affiliation) it's very easy:

```
from pybliometrics.scopus import ScopusSearch

q = "ISSN(0036-8075)"  # Query of the journal SoftwareX
s = ScopusSearch(q)  # Handles access, retrieval and parsing
pubs = s.results  # This is a list of namedtuples, one for each publication

data = []
for pub in pubs:
    if not pub.author_ids:
        continue
    authors = pub.author_ids.split(";")
    affs = pub.author_afids.split(";")  # Multiple affiliations joined on hyphen!
    data.extend(list(zip(authors, affs)))
```

We designed the information such that missing affiliations are simply stored as empty string.